# how to get a number from div then multiply

Tags: javascript, jquery

my result is the following
**Showing 5 to 40 of 50 entries** i need to get the total entries ignoring "Showing 5 to 40 of" and keeping  the number "50" insert it into input total then multiply it by 10

```html
<div class="info" id="info">Showing 30 to 40 of 50 entries</div>

<input type="text" id="total" name="total">
<input type="text" id="total" name="x10">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is with the **strong** assumption that the text always shows "Showing 5 to 40 of 50 entries" or a similar text, you'd also need to change the id for one of the boxes, as all id should be unique to be useable in the js code

```js
// use js to get the value
const info = document.getElementById("info").innerHTML
// get an array of text seperated by space
const texts = info.split(" ")
// get the 2nd last character
const number = parseInt(texts[texts.length - 2])

// put those values into the input boxes
document.getElementById("total").value = number
document.getElementById("totalTimes10").value = number*10
```

```html
<div class="info" id="info">Showing 30 to 40 of 50 entries</div>

<input type="text" id="total" name="total">
<input type="text" id="totalTimes10" name="x10">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Node.textContent` property of the node to get the `text content` of div and then use `String.split()` method to extract the total entries.

```js
const text = document.querySelector("#info").textContent.split(" ");
const entries = text[text.length - 2];
document.querySelector("#total").value = entries;
document.querySelector("#totalTimes10").value = 10 * entries;
```

```html
<div class="info" id="info">Showing 30 to 40 of 50 entries</div>

<input type="text" id="total" name="total">
<input type="text" id="totalTimes10" name="x10">
```